# Are there any GUI toolkits built on top of HTML Canvas like swing,swt,gtk or qt?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, user-interface, canvas

Are there any GUI toolkits built on top of HTML Canvas like swing,swt,gtk or qt? So that it is possible to build applications like applets or flex gui:s inside the html canvas.

Comment: Yes, http://www.zebkit.com/

Comment: It seems that broadway, a GDK backend allows somehow to display GTK apps in the canvas of the browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mozilla Labs' [Bespin](http://labs.mozilla.com/bespin/) project currently uses their own toolkit called [Thunderhead](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Thunderhead). It's written by and for the Bespin developers, but it's a separate project that could be used for anything. You will need a (free) Bespin account to try it, since there aren't any other projects that I know of that use it.

I've never used it, but I know it uses the DOM and a subset of CSS plus it's own CSS-like properties. I doubt the API is very stable though since it's experimental and evolves with the needs of the Bespin developers.

Answer (score 1):

EasleJS is a great framework!

http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

Answer (score 0):

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) looks really interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ample SDK JavaScript UI Framework](http://www.amplesdk.com/). One of the UI technologies it enables cross-browser is XUL, styleable in CSS and programmable in JavaScript with XUL DOM or jQuery APIs. You can also create your own UI technology on top of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

kineticjs is a good one, uses layers dragndrop collisiondetection events sprites etc

Answer (score 0):

KineticJS and Three.js are both good ones.  I am using KineticJS now and it makes life much easier especially for sprites/animations or general stuff you might use in games.

Answer (score -1):

It seems, Cappuccino is what you want. But the speed isn't so impressive, not yet anyways.

http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/

Take a look at the demos. I really hope the project will find the support it deserves.

Getting a firm overview of the best frameworks out there took me over a month. I will write a summary shortly.

Comment: I assumed the OP asks about replacing classical GUIs with Canvas based web-GUIs of which Cappuccino, at least to some extend, classifies. Actually, would you let me know how you interpreted the question?

Answer (score -6):

Canvas is NOT SVG. Read this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_%28HTML_element%29)

Be aware that  is noy fully supported by all browsers