# Javascript + Canvas = Mobile App, is there a UI framework for that

Tags: javascript, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any GUI toolkits built on top of HTML Canvas like swing,swt,gtk or qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572740/are-there-any-gui-toolkits-built-on-top-of-html-canvas-like-swing-swt-gtk-or-qt)

What I want to know is.. Is there a JS framework that allow to build UI on top of Canvas? I want to build website that ALL controls text and images and animations rendered in canvas.

I'm not talking about Game development, I'm talking about UI \ Mobile Web \ Mobile Apps

PS: I know it's a weird but I really whanna give it a try..

Comment: @GolezTrol that question in UNANSWERD! Mozilla project is closed.. so my question is still valid..

Comment: It's not unanswered (which I can read perfectly fine in lowercase). It *may* be that the accepted answer it not what you need, but still... Bespin is closed, but it uses [Thunderhead](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Thunderhead), which is still available, although it seems to be not updated for a while. But fortunately, there are other answers than the one that was accepted, each linking to a different library or framework. Can't imaging you read all those in just 20 minutes.

Comment: Sounds like you need a canvas library like [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com)

Comment: @GolezTrol you wasn't on the " Thunderhead " web site? Don't you? " Thunder is not yet official released " ...

Comment: @kangx yes, something like that but with controls (buttons, combobox, etc.) build in canvas...

Comment: @Ai_boy It may not be 'officially released', but it's there for download, you could at least have a look, try it, and do so too with the other linked frameworks.

Comment: @GolezTrol, ii really sorry but i didn't find a link to download page, if you can help me, plz give me this link

Comment: It's a mercurial repository. It's a vcs, similar to git.